# UIView respond to orientation change after animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, rotation, orientation

How can I make my UIView (which has no access to the ViewController) perform some task *after* an orientation change has taken place? That is, no task should take place until the animation has completely finished and the frame is no longer changing due to animation.

I've tried registering an observer on the UIView to respond to UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotifications, but a breakpoint I've placed in the handler is triggered *before* the animation even starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to involve the view controller. Only the view controller can get a reference to the transition coordinator, so that it can call `animate(alongsideTransition:completion:)` and do something in the completion handler. That is the moment when the animation has finished.

So the view controller could then talk directly to the view, or, if you want the view to be completely agnostic, the view controller could post a custom notification for which the view has registered.

Comment: However, you should probably rethink this. A UIView is view. In all likelihood, whatever it is you're up to, the view controller should probably be in charge of the whole thing. If you're doing layout, the view controller can set things up before the rotation starts and the change will be animated along with the rotation, which is way cool. If you're changing some content, that's a controller  job, not a view job.

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for the suggestion. I suspected grabbing a reference to the view controller would be the only solution. Basically I'm working on a library for a video player, so we don't necessarily have access to the view controller at the library level, but I could set up a public API for passing a reference to the view controller. What I need to do is reorient custom captions in the view based on orientation change.